# Champagne Pyramid Distribution Puzzle

Tags: algorithm

I recently interviewed with Microsoft and they asked me the following puzzle, for which I had to write an algorithm and accompanying test cases. I wasn't able to crack it and it still is a puzzle to me.

Problem Statement :

A champagne pyramid is a pyramid made of champagne glasses , each of equal capacity say , n.
The pyramid begins with one glass at the top level , two glasses at the second level , then three below that and so on up to infinite levels. A level x of the pyramid thus has x no. of champagne glasses.

A steady stream of champagne is poured down from the top level,which trickles down to the lower levels. What is the distribution of champagne in the glasses at a given level i.

The problem is quite abstract and those are all the inputs I was given.

Comment: Guess it depends on how the champagne overflows out of each glass...

Comment: I asked the same to the interviewer and all I was told is that it would overflow proportionally into the glasses at the lower level.

Comment: What does he mean by proportionally? I think the answer is basically just Pascal's triangle (with each row divided by 2^row), and that's what I would say, but (as with many interview questions) it is quite vague.

Comment: Exactly my point . I tried prodding him to get to know what "proportionally" meant but he didn't explain it anymore. :(

Comment: Similar to this question: [Find the amount of water in ith cup in a pyramid structure?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11764582)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is [Normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) I believe.

Have a look at the diagram:

```
           |1|
           ---
        |2|   |3|
        ---   ---
     |4|   |5|   |6|
     ---   ---   ---
   |7|  |8|   |9|   |10|
   ---  ---   ---   ----
```

Let's say you have a flow of X

1 will flow into 2,3 uniformly, thus each gets 1/2X

each will flow uniformly to the glasses below it, so 4 gets 1/4X, 6 gets 1/4X and 5 gets 2*1/4X= 1/2X

At next level - the same principle applies:

```
7 gets 1/8X
8 gets 1/8X from 4 and 1/4X from 5, totaling 3/8X,
9 gets same as 8 and 10 same as 8.
```

At infinity - it should converge into normal distribution.

At any finite number `i` - it should be `f(i,n)/ 2^(i-1)` where `f(i,n)` is the `n`th [binomial number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) for level `i` polynomial. As @veredmarald indicated in comments, that distribution function is actually [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for p = 1/2, thus giving you `flow(i)~Bin(i-1,1/2)`

Comment: You are too fast for me amit! Halfway through typing mostly the same thing. One small note, the above assumes that the overflow from each glass is distributed evenly between the two glasses it stands upon, and there is no loss/spillage between levels.

Comment: @verdesmarald: Yes, actually - it does take these assumptions. Without the no loss assumption, it should add some lossness factor which is exponentially growing as function of `i` that describes the loss of the flow.

Comment: Also related: [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: @verdesmarald: Thanks for the comment. It is actually a perfect fit for p=1/2. I added it to the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the distribution is even, even though the flow of the champagne follows the binomial distribution, which at infinity approaches the Normal Distribution.

The glass size has finite volume.