# Find the time it takes fluid to reach the nth cup

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

This is an additional assignment that i got from my teacher.

Cups are arranged in a treelike structure, something like this:

```
  1
 2 3
4 5 6
```

It takes 10 seconds to fill up cup 1, then it overflows into cup 2 and 3. (Assume there is no spillage). Cups 2 and 3 then take 20 seconds to fill up due to the water flow being split. In total, to fill up cup 3 by pouring water into cup 1, it would take 30 seconds. For cup 5 it would take 50 seconds, and so on.

Here is a table with the correct values for the row and seconds fluid takes to reach the next cup.

```
    1(10)
 2(30) 3(30)
4(70) 5(50) 6(70)
```

The problem proposed is to solve this for an arbritrary number of rows with the boundary of r <= 50:
Given the row r and the cup c, how long will it take for that cup to fill?

I have been racking my head over this for around 24 hours now, and i am no closer to solving it. I know that this has something to do with Pascal's triangle and Recursion. I would also like to note that this is not a graded assignment, but just an ungraded interesting problem proposed by a teacher.

EDIT:
Added a more comprehensible data structure along with my notes.

```
1:   1
2:  1 2
3: 1 2 3
```

Given this structure i have figured out that the proportions of water flow distribution to the cups below it is relevant to Pascal's triangle according to the following formula

```
h(r,c)=P(n,c)/2^(n-1)
where P(n,c) returns the number contained in the according row in Pascal's triangle
```

Then i used this to calculate the seconds with the following formula:

```
t(r,c)=(2^(n-1)/P(n,c))*10
```

This is true for the first 3 rows, but falls apart after that because of the fact that then the flow of water from 2 cups above a cup does not start at the same time.

I also tried an recursive function which would calculate its parents, which reside in (r-1,c) and (r-1,c-1) and apply the previous formula, but it was incorrect due to the reason i explained above.

Comment: Your first and last sentences of this question are somewhat at odds with one another...

Comment: cup 5 should take 60 seconds. and it beats me how you spent 24 hours on this. you know the number of cups in the rows, one cup is 10 seconds, multiply, profit...

Comment: A half-answer: You're on the right track with Pascal's triangle. One thing, though: Don't think in terms of the "time to fill", but in the "fill rate": 0.1 for cup 1, 0.05 for cups 2 and 3, etc.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think it's 50 since both 2 and 3 flow into it once full (after 30 seconds) so it would fill at the same rate as they did

Comment: That's not a tree if a node has more than one parent.

Comment: @StephenTG. Sorry, what i mean is that it is not a graded assignment, but just sort of an additional one for fun.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, cup 5 takes 50 seconds due to cup 1 taking 10 seconds, 2 and 3 taking 20 and then 5 has the same flow as cup 2 had originally. 1/4 + 1/4 = 1/2. I spent 24 hours on this due to me being busy with work and stuff, its just been in the back of my head for a while.

Comment: This looks more like a mathematical question than a python question. Are you asking for code on how to solve this? If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I noticed a pattern where if you calculate the value of `r C c` it equals the sum of the proportions of each cup's contribution into the cup `r,c`. (Let me explain.) You'll have to change your number scheme, but in this case, cup 5 is cup `2,1`. `2 C 1 = 2`. You'll notice that cup 1 gives all of its water to parents of cup 5, so that's a ratio of `1`. Cups 2 and 3 only give half of their water to cup 5, so they each have a ratio of `0.5`. This didn't hold for cups on the edge of the triangle, though.

Comment: Assume there is no spillage <-> due to the water flow being split ???

Comment: We use python in the class, but now that i think about it i'll remove the tag.

Comment: I added what i have tried and figured out so far.

Comment: @Gangnus, yes, the water can only go in those 2 directions once the cup has filled.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764582/find-the-amount-of-water-in-ith-cup-in-a-pyramid-structure.

Comment: @Glenn, i saw that question, but i couldn`t apply it to this for a solution for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to this interview question are given at http://www.careercup.com/question?id=9820788 and http://www.careercup.com/question?id=22191662.

It's also at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-water-in-a-glass/, and for completeness's sake, here's the related SO questioned I linked in the comment: [Find the amount of water in ith cup in a pyramid structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764582/find-the-amount-of-water-in-ith-cup-in-a-pyramid-structure).

Answer (score 0):

Here recurrence relation which can be used to find solution using Dynamic programming :-

```
if(T(r-1,c-1)<T(r,c)) {

  T(r,c) = T(r-1,c) + (1-F(r-1,c)*(T(r-1,c)-T(r-1,c-1)))/(F(r-1,c-1)+F(r-1,c));
  F(r,c) = F(r-1,c) + F(r-1,c-1);
}

else if(T(r-1,c)<T(r-1,c-1)) {

   T(r,c) = T(r-1,c-1) + (1-F(r-1,c-1)*(T(r-1,c-1)-T(r-1,c)))/(F(r-1,c-1)+F(r-1,c));
   F(r,c) = F(r-1,c) + F(r-1,c-1);
}

else {

   T(r,c) = T(r-1,c-1) + 1/F(r-1,c-1);
   F(r,c) = F(r-1,c-1);
}

for corner cases like  
T(r,1) = T(r-1,1) + 2/F(r-1,1) and T(r,r) = T(r-1,r-1) + 2/F(r-1,r-1) and T(1,1) = 10

F(1,1) = 1/10
```

**Note:** I think there is a possible closed form but hard to solve